# Зачем перегружать операции? с++

Tags: c++, ооп, перегрузка-операторов

Доброго времени суток.

Мне нужно создать класс с методом

```
y(z) = 7.2*sin(z) + (2-z)
```

и при этом использовать перегрузку операций.

> В разрабатываемом классе перегрузите  потоковые операции для объектов  класса. Для выполнения задания предложенного варианта перегрузите необходимые математические операции.

Я уже почитал об перегрузке операций, но не совсем понимаю как ее тут можно применить... Пытался найти подобный пример в поисковике, но что-то не вышло.
**Так зачем в данном задании использовать перегрузку операций?**

Comment: В образовательных целях, вероятно.

Comment: Это очевидно, но как тут его применить в данной функции?) Ну т.е. я перегружу операции, но они же должны будут выполнить такую же функцию как и без перегрузки. Вот и я не понимаю как их перегрузить правильно...

Comment: Почитайте спецификацию языка, реализовать (обьявить) и всё, хотя бы на msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dhe1hce.aspx

Comment: Ладно тогда просто обьявлю их и использую. Я просто думал тут есть какая-то причина их использования...

Comment: А что у Вас `z`? И что в этом классе будет кроме этого метода?

Comment: конструктор по умолчанию;
конструктор инициализации; 
конструктор преобразования базового типа к типу, определяемому разрабатываемым классом;
В разрабатываемом классе перегрузите  потоковые операции для объектов  класса. Для выполнения задания предложенного варианта перегрузите необходимые математические операции.
При разработке класса вашего варианта учтите индивидуальные уточнения для функций – членов класса.
Разработайте для объектов вашего класса предложенные в каждом варианте пользовательские функци. z это плогаю значение функции y)

Comment: Я так понимаю ваш класс должен потреблять входные данные через потоковые операции. Например, если **myObject** экземпляр вашего класса, то инструкция **myObject >> z;** должна скормить аргумент **z** вашему методу **y** и вернуть результирующее значение.

Comment: Ну с потоковыми операциями я так и хотел сделать :3 Я просто с математическими операциями в осадок упал...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, должно получиться примерно так:

```
class DoubleWrapper{
  double value;

  public:

  DoubleWrapper(): value{0} {} 
  explicit DoubleWrapper(double v): value{v} {}
  DoubleWrapper(const DoubleWrapper&) = default;

  // Потоковый оператор для вывода значения 
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, DoubleWrapper rha){
    return out << value;
  }

  friend DoubleWrapper operator - (double lha, DoubleWrapper rha){
     return DoubleWrapper{lha - rha.value};
  }
};

...

DoubleWrapper v2 {2};
DoubleWrapper v7 = 9 - v2;
std::cout << v7; // 7

...

DoubleWrapper y (DoubleWrapper z){
   retun 7.2*sin(z) + (2-z);
}
```

Нужно добавить остальные мат. операции и функцию sin(DoubleWrapper). Только фраза "конструктор преобразования базового типа к типу, определяемому разрабатываемым классом" у меня вызывает недоумение.